# Localhost Cookies Options

Tags: express, cookies, nestjs, localhost

I am developing a Chrome Extension that modifies the UI of Google Calendar based of configurations in my server.

**In production is working great.** However, I cannot make it work on development. I know the problem to be the following:

- The request comes from a script (not navigation, so `sameSite=Lax` does not work) from a different origin *(https://calendar.google.com)*
- In localhost I am unable to set `sameSite=None` since that requires `secure=true` but setting it that way, the cookies are not even sent back *(I cannot see them in the Network tab of Chrome Dev Tools)*, that is probably Express filtering them out...

I am using Express and NestJS.

Is there another way I could avoid installing certs locally so that http://localhost:3000 becomes httpS://localhost:3000. The reason why I want to avoid that is because if we start hiring people, I do not want to overburden them in their onboarding with that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting up a remote dev environment on the cloud that handles the https for you.